# msysgit vim cursorline is dark on my light background. how to set it to light or off

Tags: windows, git, vim, msysgit, color-scheme

I have msysgit version 1.7.0.2-preview20100309 on windows 7
and my console windows has light background with dark text
when I open a file in vim (the vim included in msysgit)
I get cursorline highlight in dark color so I can't really see my text

for my own installation of gvim I use github256 color scheme but that has no effect in console.

I have looked at /share/vim/vimrc to see what's set there.
I changed cursorline to 'set nocursorline' and 'set background=light' but it has no effect. 
How do I style my vim in msysgit?
How do I get rid of this dark cursorline
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly set the syntax coloration by specifying something like the following:

```
hi CursorLine guibg=#ffffff guifg=#000000 gui=NONE ctermbg=white ctermfg=black cterm=NONE term=reverse
```

You *can* include the above line your '~/.vimrc'. However, in the ideal case, setting the CursorLine highlight should be done in by the color scheme file being sourced by '~/.vimrc'. Most (well-written) color schemes should define a suitable CursorLine highlight as a matter of course. I would suggest using something like [Pyte](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1492) or my own [MayanSmoke](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3065).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to look at colors/schemename.vim files. I set 
hi CursorLine ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=yellow cterm=NONE
This fixes the line. I will dig into updating my github256.vim colors 
I also suspect the msysgit is not 256 color enabled. not sure about that one.